Никак не могу подключить mongoose в приложение Electron
Стоит мне добавить в файл index.js строку const mongoose = require('mongoose'), как я тут же получаю ошибку:
\jsWoodApp\node_modules\bson\lib\bson.cjs:170
        TextDecoderFatal ??= new TextDecoder('utf8', { fatal: true });
                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:18)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (\jsWoodApp\node_modules\electron-compile\lib\require-hook.js:77:14)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:728:14)
    at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:853:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\jsWoodApp\node_modules\mongodb\lib\bson.js:9:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968:30)

Я пробовал переустанавливать библиотеки, подключать mongoose через импорт, но это не помогло. Я себе даже представить не могу, что идёт не так. Пока я не пытаюсь использовать mongoose, всё работает нормально.
Версия node 18.18.1

Версия node.js какая?

добавил - 18.18.1
